# Why didn't anyone in the school notice that Natsume is actually a female?

Tags: tokyo-ravens

In the early episodes of Tokyo Ravens, Natsume is seen wearing a boy's uniform. It is said that this is due to some customs in their family. As quoted from Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tokyo_Ravens_characters):

> As a family tradition, she has to present herself as male in front of other onmyouji families, a tradition that was created to hide the true identity of Yakou's reincarnation.

But why didn't anyone notice that she is actually a girl? Everyone except Touji and Harutora who already knew her, assume that she's a boy.

Comment: cuz of onmyoudou and a special tsukimikado "heirloom". Its explained in detail later on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several reasons why no one noticed that Natsume was a girl:

1. She was dressing as a boy, therefore no one should suspect her.
2. On the novel, an onmyouji can identify whether you're a girl or boy based on your aura. Boys naturally have yang aura and girls have yin aura. 
   Normally, when a practitioner has a shikigami, the shikigami's aura should be the opposite so that their compatibility will be in harmony.
   However, Natsume's prideful shikigami which is Hokuto have a yin aura, therefore it made conflict in their auras, thus negating the yin aura and making it a yang aura. In result, anyone would assume that Natsume was indeed a boy.
3. It is rumored that Natsume was Yakou's reincarnation, since she was the next heir of the Tsuchimikado family, they preconceived that she is a boy.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After *finished watching the anime's first season* (hoping for a 2nd one), I have now an answer to my own question.

Just to clarify things, (**SPOILER on hidden text**)

- Natsume being a girl was revealed on [Tokyo Ravens episode 17](http://tokyo-ravens.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ravens_Episode_17) and her being a boy was explained then from [episode 18](http://tokyo-ravens.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ravens_Episode_18), [19](http://tokyo-ravens.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ravens_Episode_19) through [episode 20](http://tokyo-ravens.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ravens_Episode_20).
- Natsume being a girl was exposed when Shaver was out of control and [started attacking them](https://www.funimation.com/shows/tokyo-ravens/videos/official/_darkness_emerge_--razor-) after a spirit disaster was unleashed.

  > Shaver tore Natsume's clothes apart which revealed the truth.
- Jin Ohtomo Sensei and the principal of the onmyouji academy as well as the Yakou fanatics and the twin horned syndicate never noticed that Natsume was a girl, until it was revealed to them. According to Jin Ohtomo, a **B-Grade Spell** was used and, although noticeable, if carefully examined via one's aura, it was never revealed. This can be linked to [catzilla's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/28294/2516):

  > However, Natsume's prideful shikigami which is Hokuto have a yin aura, therefore it made conflict in their auras, thus negating the yin aura and making it a yang aura. In result, anyone would assume that Natsume was indeed a boy.
- On [episode 20](http://tokyo-ravens.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ravens_Episode_20), it was revealed that Natsume's father told her about the family tradition when she was in junior high. After that, the times that Harutora came to hang out drastically reduced.

  > That was when Natsume decided to make the familiar Hokuto to continue hanging out with Harutora. although this was a secret even to Harutora.
- The cross-dressing was endorsed by Yasuzumi Tsuchimikado **to hide the identity of the reincarnation of Yakou** (Polaris King)

  > The real reincarnation was not Natsume but Harutora Tsuchimikado. It was also to conceal Natsume being a fake as she was a girl. From the moment they were born they switched Natsume and Harutora was set on the branch family. Harutora who has tremendous aura and energy, was put under a curse to hide this and also concealed of his abilities one of is being a spirit seer. The curse was confirmed by Kakugyouki the one-hand ogre.